# Minecraft server connection timeout on Mac OS X version 10.6.8

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I was trying to connect to a new server that i saw that other people are capable of connecting to but im unable to connect to it and it keeps saying "io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: (server IP)"

For some reason it's not letting me join and its said that on another server ive been playing on and said this on another server "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /(server IP)

Ive tried methods for fixing problems for this but when i try terminal the commands dont work and the other 2 servers used to work for me but suddenly stopped working a few days ago.

Comment: are you including the correct port?

Comment: by "port" do you mean IP?

Comment: Both, port and IP. the port follows the IP, and if the server doesn't use the default port of 25565 you have to enter it manually when you connect like this XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:#####

Comment: it said the same thing when i tried it manually.